# Why hookOnComplete() not being called sometimes in my case?

Tags: project-reactor

I have a really complicated flux here, something like this:

```java
private Object run(Flux<Pair<String, Flux<Record>>> flux) throws InterruptedException {

    BlockingQueue<Object> result = new SynchronousQueue<>();

    flux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .parallel(2, 1)
            .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .flatMap(pair -> pair.getRight().parallel()
                    .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                    .flatMap(record -> stringToError(record))
                    .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Complete " + pair.getLeft()))) // @log
            .sequential()
            .buffer(1000)
            .subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<List<Error>>() {
                @Override
                protected void hookOnComplete() {
                    result.offer(Boolean.TRUE);
                }
                @Override
                protected void hookOnError(Throwable throwable) {
                    result.offer(throwable);
                }
                @Override
                protected void hookOnCancel() {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
            });

    return result.take();
}
```

It runs pretty well except that **sometimes** it **blocked forever**.

NO `hookOnComplete()`, NO `hookOnError()`, NO `hookOnCancel()`.

And when this happened, line `@log` does already print all data I feed in. That's so strange.

I don't know how to deal with this.

Can anyone tells me what can I do and what could cause this?

By the way, I use reactor-core 3.3.2 here.

Comment: Nothing obvious there that I can see which will sometimes block (and other times not.) Are you sure it's not your source flux which is blocking? (A [mcve] would also be helpful.)

Comment: The `Flux` is done. And even there are no threads in the `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`. But `result.take()` never return. I can not provide a reproducible example, because it **somethimes** block. Is there anything suspicious?
@MichaelBerry

Comment: Is this because your buffer 1000? May be it is waiting for 1000 items to accumulate?

Comment: No, because when all upstream complete, the `buffer(1000)` will return immediately. @vins